# Update JavaScript event when AJAX-loading new html

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I load some new HTML to my page, via a template like so:

```
$.post("templates/single.html", function(data){
    $("#feed").append(
        data.replace( /{{title}}/ , "Title")
            .replace( /{{subtitle}}/ , "Subtitle")
            .replace( /{{text}}/ , val.fragment)
    );
});
```

This request is done several times, so the `data` that is returned contains div tags with `class="togglethis"`. I want to add an event listener with jQuery that listens to those classes being clicked.

Naturally I would add the event listener, like this one:

```
$.post("templates/single.html", function(data){
    $("#feed").append(/*skipped code here*/);

    $(".content").hide();
    $(".togglethis").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

right after the `$("#feed).append()`-part but then the event that is fired as many times as templates loaded. That is, if I load 25 items with this template, the "content" next to a "togglethis" will togggle back and forth 25 times before stopping.

Where should I put my event-handler to only make it fire once? Or, am I thinking wrong from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.live()` or `.on()` functionality. Both of these automatically re-bind events for loaded content.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

Your divs are dynamically created so, depending on the version of jQuery you are using, you need the `jQuery.live()` or `jQuery.on()` method

> **jQuery.live() *since jQuery 1.3*** an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **jQuery.on()  *since jQuery 1.7*** - Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

#### Sample

```
$(".togglethis").live("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
});
```

or

```
$(".togglethis").on("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Where should I put that live/on-code? If I put it inside my ajax callback (as before) the toggle still fires 25 times. If I put it right outside the ajax call nothing happens.

Comment: Put it outside your callback, you only need this executes once per page, not every time the callback has success.

Answer (score 0):

Use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) syntax of jQuery:

```
$(".togglethis").live('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Where should I put that live/on-code? If I put it inside my ajax callback (as before) the toggle still fires 25 times. If I put it right outside the ajax call nothing happens.

Comment: Put it once, outside the ajax call but be inside the $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like now, anything wrong?

```
$(".togglethis").on("click", function(){
    $(this).siblings(".content").slideToggle();
});

$.post("templates/single.html", function(data){
    $("#feed").append(
        data.replace( /{{title}}/ , "Title")
            .replace( /{{subtitle}}/ , "Subtitle")
            .replace( /{{text}}/ , val.fragment)
        );
    $(".content").hide();
});
```